# Double borders on one element - pure css - no wrapping div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following effect using only one element, I want to remove the wrapper div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kdvex

I've almost acheive the desired effect by using an inset shadow and a border. But the curved borders look a bit wrong. Look at the edges of the blue bit to see what I mean.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uLKjl

Can anyone improve on this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Looks same to me with ff. Doesn't work with chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Cadence96's suggestion of using the pseudo selector for the second border:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdcne

Answer (score 1):

I added an element that simulates the border with after pseudo element.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxemK

```
.btn.blue {
  z-index:2;
  position:relative
}

.btn.blue:after {content:"."; position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width:99.6%; height: 24px; background:none; z-index:1; border:2px solid white; 
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-ms-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;}
```

SECOND ANSWER: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxemK

```
.btn.blue {
  z-index:2;
  position:relative; line-height:100%;
}  



    .btn.blue:after {content:"."; position: absolute; left:0; top:0; 
  width:99.6%; background:none; z-index:1; border:2.2px solid white; 
  line-height:133%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -ms-border-radius: 7px;
    -o-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;}
```

Comment: That's almost there, unfortunately it needs to be variable height as the font size is likely to change.

Comment: Then remove the height and play with the line height of the anchor and the :after pseudo element. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxemK I gave the anchor 100% line-height, the anchor :after has a greater line-height of 133%.